# Javssist generated empty class

Tags: android, gradle, transform, aop

In my Android Project, I try to use Transform API and Javasist to make an AOP framework.

But some class is transformed to an empty class and then I got the build error :

```
/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar] (Can't process class  xxx/xxx/xxx/ABC.class
```

because the ABC.class get empty after javasist handle(I just load it with javasiit and then write back).

The code I write to modify class is :

```
 public void weave(String path) {
    println("Begin to weave androidClassPath = " + androidClassPath)
    println("Begin to weave path = " + path)
    pool.appendClassPath(path)
    pool.appendClassPath(androidClassPath)
    pool.importPackage("android.util.Log");
    File dir = new File(path)
    int indexOfPackage = path.length() + 1;
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        dir.eachFileRecurse { File file ->
            String filePath = file.absolutePath
            if (isWeavableClass(filePath)) {
                println("Begin to inject filePath " + filePath)
                int end = filePath.length() - 6 // .class = 6
                String className = filePath.substring(indexOfPackage, end).replace(File.separator, '.')
                CtClass clazz = pool.getCtClass(className)
                if (clazz.isFrozen()) {
                    clazz.defrost()
                }
                boolean timeDebugClass = false;
                boolean parameterDebugClass = false;
                if(clazz.hasAnnotation(TimingDebug.class)) {
                    timeDebugClass = true;
                }
                if(clazz.hasAnnotation(ParameterDebug.class)) {
                    parameterDebugClass = true;
                }
                println "timeDebugClass = "+ timeDebugClass + " parameterDebugClass = " + parameterDebugClass
                CtMethod[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (CtMethod method : methods) {
                    boolean emptyMethod = method.isEmpty()
                    boolean isNativeMethod = Modifier.isNative(method.getModifiers());
                    println("method name = " + method + " emptyMethod " + emptyMethod + " isNativeMethod = " + isNativeMethod)
                    if (!emptyMethod && !isNativeMethod) {
                        if (method.hasAnnotation(ParameterDebug.class) || parameterDebugClass) {
                            weaveParameterDebugMethod(clazz, method)
                        }
                        if (method.hasAnnotation(TimingDebug.class) || timeDebugClass) {
                            weaveTimingDebugMethod(clazz, method)
                        }
                    }
                }
                CtConstructor[] constructors = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
                for(CtConstructor constructor: constructors){
                    boolean emptyMethod = constructor.isEmpty()
                    println("constructor name = " + constructor + " emptyMethod " + emptyMethod)
                    if (!emptyMethod) {
                        if (constructor.hasAnnotation(ParameterDebug.class) || parameterDebugClass) {
                            weaveParameterDebugMethod(clazz, constructor)
                        }
                        if (constructor.hasAnnotation(TimingDebug.class) || timeDebugClass) {
                            weaveTimingDebugMethod(clazz, constructor)
                        }
                    }
                }
                clazz.writeFile(path)
                clazz.detach()
            }
        }
    }
}
```